# Update Dynamic column values using select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have two temp table: temp1 and temp 2.

temp 1 is

```
Reg Key | Player Name | Age
----------------------------
1       |  Null       | Null
2       |  Null       | Null
3       |  Null       | Null
```

temp 2 is

```
Reg Key | Question Name | value
----------------------------
1       | Player Name   | Ronaldo
2       | Player Name   | Zedan
1       | Age           | 35
2       | Age           | 38
```

in temp 1 the column name is dynamic except for [Reg Key], for example I need to update the row with [Reg Key] 1 in temp 1 with 'Ronaldo' and 35 from the table temp 2.

I used to loop to get the values from temp 2 and update temp 1, but the records in the table temp 2 now exceed 5 thousand, so I'm trying to create an `UPDATE` query, but I don't know how to get the columns name at run time.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like pivot might do the trick:

```
select 1 as regkey, 'Player Name' as Question_name, 'Ronaldo' as value into #temp2
union all select 2, 'Player Name', 'Zedan'
union all select 1, 'Age', '35'
union all select 2, 'Age', '38'

Select 
    regkey
    , [Player Name]
    , [Age]
From #temp2
Pivot (max(value) for Question_Name in ([Player Name], [Age])) as pvt
```

Comment: tnx to give the trick of pivot table.i try to used pivot table but it returns same no of rows in first row they assign player name Ronaldo and in second row player name is null and age is set in 35 against registration 1. i want to assign these two values in one row...?plz need ur comments